# How to use css and js compressor in cakephp2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

May be duplicate.but please help me am not getting any easy stuff.

I want to enable css and js  compressor in cakephp2.

so how to include css and js on view???

I have set

```
Configure::write('Asset.filter.css', 'css.php');
```

but there is no any css.php in webroot.

Comment: What plugin are you using? Cake doesn't come with a compressor. See: https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress

Comment: Costa i have tried that plugin but am not getting the steps to enable it,so please can you guide me

Comment: Too complex to guide you, did you go through the docs? https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress/wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed (actually modified) one plugin for exactly what you need

You can get that on github over here

```
https://github.com/Er-Kalpesh/CakePHP-Combinator-Plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

Minifying/Compressing css and js through php is not the best use of resources. Its better to minify or compress these files before you deploy to the live server.

If you have access to node.js you can use lesscss and uglifyjs to minify your css and javascsipt.

the gnu gzip utility can be used to compress these files even further

Comment: no actually previously i have used one plugin which compresses css and js in storing that in one directory and including those css and js in html,so its we can use benefits of catch.now at here whenever we change css or js file it automatically update compress version of css and js.so thats the nice thing I think :)